# C# implemenation of IDL declaration with an INT_PTR

Tags: c#, 64-bit, idl

We have a method declared in an idl file like this:

```
[id(7), helpstring("method SomeFunction")] HRESULT SomeFunction([in] INT_PTR windowHandle, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL* dlgResult);
```

We do the implementation of it in C# with this method:

```
public bool SomeFunction(int windowHandle)
```

That works fine when building 32 bit, however when we build x64 the types don't match as the idl is looking for a 64 bit value and the c# expects a 32 bit value.

Using IntPtr in the C# doesn't work because the code needs a long or an int in c#.

Is there any type i can use in the c# method that will compile to long or int depending on the platform?

I'd rather not have to duplicate code by having the function twice, and i'm not sure we can change the IDL to just use Int64 due to backwards compatibility.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go into Project Properties... and to the Build tab.

In there, you can find "Conditional compilation symbols", add WIN64 for your x64 platform. Save.

For "AnyCPU", you probably want to remove that platform...

Then in code use:

```
#if WIN64
     long handle;
     public bool SomeFunction(long windowHandle)
#else
     int handle;
     public bool SomeFunction(int windowHandle)
#endif
```

However I think you can use the IntPtr and convert its value to an int/long depending on its Size property...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `IntPtr` wouldn't work for you? The `IntPtr` structure has a constructor overload that takes an `Int32`, and another that takes an `Int64`. Additionally, it has a `ToInt32()` method and a `ToInt64()` method. Your code would work something like this:

```
public bool SomeFunction(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    // Implementation here.
    // If you need the value of the pointer in the implementation,
    // you can use:
    // long actualValue = windowHandle.ToInt64();
}

long actualHandle = 1234;
IntPtr handlePtr = new IntPtr(actualHandle);
bool returnValue = SomeFunction(windowHandle);
```

Comment: your code at the bottom looks like it will work, however that's all C# code. The problem I'm having is the the method is declared in an IDL file which causes the C# code to error with: csfile.cs (37): 'csnamespace.csproject.csfile' does not implement interface member 'cpplib.Icppinterface.SomeFunction(long)'    I get that error when compiling x64 whether i use and int or an IntPtr in the C# method.  If i use an IntPtr it also doesn't compile for 32 bit because the signature is looking specifically for an  int.

Comment: You're right, my solution won't work for you; I didn't read carefully enough. The problem is exactly that you're using INT_PTR in the IDL, and I assume you're using such a mechanism for COM compatibility. You can see [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810720.aspx) for a discussion of the problem from the IDL perspective. Yes, it's 12 years old, but I think it's still relevant for your situation, particularly the section devoted to INT_PTR and LONG_PTR.